# How to execute mongodb query in java

Tags: java, node.js, mongodb-query

Is it possible to execute MongoDB query within java, same as SQL query execution, by using property file?
I have a java-script file which contains query to fetch data from MongoDB. I can execute the file in command prompt?

```
var user1=function()
{ 
   print(db.Employee_Details.find().toArray()); 
}
user1();
```

This is a simple java-script file. Can I execute this file using java program?

Comment: What do you exactly got in line 1? Please, edit your question with relevant pieces of code.

Comment: Also, are you using java or javascript? They are not the same. Modify your tags accordingly.